# I just formatted my external hard drive, so why the is used space huge?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, gparted

I used gparted to format my 1TB external HDD to ext4. I am new to linux and all but after formatting almost 15GiB of space is used. Is this normal? Is this how large the ext4 is? I am going to use this to store a lot of videos and the more videos I can fit the better.

Comment: The HDD is brand new and it has 1TB(not TiB) of space. Since it is brand new it has NTFS, thus the reason for formatting.

Comment: Could you please print here result of comand `sudo fdisk -l`

Answer (score 2):

When creating ext4 fs, usually you should reserve some space for system daemons needs. Quote from `mkfs` man page:

```
Set the percentage of the filesystem which may only be
allocated by privileged processes. Reserving some number 
of  filesystem  blocks  for  use by privileged processes
is done to avoid filesystem fragmentation, and to allow 
system daemons, such as syslogd(8), to continue to function
correctly after non-privileged processes  are prevented from
writing to the filesystem.  Normally, the default percentage
of reserved blocks is 5%.
```

So by default `mkfs` keeps 5%, in case of 1Tb it may 50Gb. I don't know what % `gparted` uses by default.

**As a summary**

Please read [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7950/reserved-space-for-root-on-a-filesystem-why) and [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ext4#Remove_reserved_blocks) carefully.

In your case, as you wish use this hard not for root ( `/` ), but as audio/video/other_need storage, you can remove reserving of blocks using `tune2fs` utility.

```
tune2fs -r 0 /dev/sdxX
```

Quote from [opensuse forum](http://forums.opensuse.org/english/other-forums/looking-something-other-than-support/454461-ext3-ext4-reserved-blocks.html):

```
If you set the reserved block count to zero, it won't affect
performance much except if you run for long periods of time (with lots
of file creates and deletes) while the filesystem is almost full
(i.e., say above 95%), at which point you'll be subject to
fragmentation problems. Ext4's multi-block allocator is much more
fragmentation resistant, because it tries much harder to find
contiguous blocks, so even if you don't enable the other ext4
features, you'll see better results simply mounting an ext3 filesystem
using ext4 before the filesystem gets completely full.

If you are just using the filesystem for long-term archive, where
files aren't changing very often (i.e., a huge mp3 or video store), it
obviously won't matter.
```

Comment: But this hdd sounds like a storage disk only not the primary disk, why does it need to be reserving space for root then?

Comment: Actually there is now need to reserve block in that case. That's the main idea of my answer. I'm sorry if it is not clear from what I write, english is not my native language.

Comment: While the reserved space is worth noting, it does not affect the used space, but rather it decreases the available space.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I will read about it more carefully, and try a few things in virtual box. I will update answer depending on results

Comment: In the wiki, it says so that 5% is too large for HDD larger than 50 GB, so how much should I use on a 1TB if I am going to use it for torrenting and stuff.

Comment: You can use 0% for this stuff.  `tune2fs -r 0 /dev/sdxX`

Answer (score 0):

There is always some space used by file management data structures. To keep track of what part of the hard disk is used by which file, the file system needs to use some of the disk space. If you are an expert user and know what you are doing then you can tweak some parameters when creating the file system to reduce the size of these management structures but that may increase the wasted space per every file. Below is the text that best describes this idea. Its not my text, just some thing that I found on internet. If you want to read the original post or need more detail plz visit this [link](http://gparted-forum.surf4.info/viewtopic.php?id=13021)

> As far as I know, ext2/3 (and maybe ext4 as well) use fixed-size management data structures that are written once during creating the file system - and never extended afterwards (unless you don't resize the file system). As a result, the management structures do always consume the same amount of space on your partition, no matter how much data you have stored there.
>   In contrast to this, some other file systems - ReiserFS is one of this kind, I think - allocate space for their management structures dynamically - that is, management structures start off consuming very little space ruight after creating the file system, but grow as you put more data on the drive. In the end, this approach can lead to the same amount of storage space used for management as in a file system that has fixed-size management structures - so don't let yourself be fooled by the amount of "used" space on your freshly-formatted ext3 partition!
>   However, there are some options that can be passed to the mkfs.ext2 command which influence the size of the management structures. Most important of these options are the -i option (this one defines the ratio of inodes per storage space - that is, you can influence how many bytes of storage space one inode should "take care of") as well as the -I option (which defines the amount of storage space occupied by one inode). Please note that these values can not be changed once the file system is created - you have to re-format the partition if you want to change one of them. And since the first of these options indirectly defines the total number of inodes on your partition, and since each inode can represent only one single file or directory, it also limits the number of files that can be stored on your partition! As a result, you can tune the number of inodes to your current needs (like, e.g., one inode per 128 MBytes - this could minimize the overhead occupied by the inodes on a file system that is reserved for storing movies, CD-ROM ISO images or other large files of several 100 MBytes each - but if you want to put your photo collection there, you won't be able to get the partition only halfway filled since you'd run out of inodes far before this point).

Comment: waaah, what I read says something totally different [link](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ext4#Remove_reserved_blocks)

Comment: @Alvar Have you read the lines just before the quote?

Comment: @user224266, this answer is preciously correct.  The used space comes from the allocation bitmaps and inode tables.  The root reserved space is not counted as used, but subtracted from the reported available space.  When root invades the reserved space, this results in an apparent over 100% usage.